Spresense SDK コンフィギュレーションが実行できない（Windows 11 IDE版）
Spresense SDK（Windows 11 IDE版）の環境構築を行っております。下記リンク先の4.3ビルドのコンフィギュレーションのところで詰まっています。
4. アプリケーション "myapps" の作成と実行 | Spresense SDK スタートガイド (IDE 版)

上画像のようにSDKコンフィグを実行すると下記のようなエラーが出力されます。
Command failed: bash -c 'make olddefconfig'
/usr/bin/bash: line 1: kconfig-conf: command not found
make: *** [tools/Unix.mk:680: olddefconfig] Error 127

解決方法が分かる方いたら教えていただけないでしょうか。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

私も同じところで詰まりました、原因が同じなら以下で治ると思います。
公式の環境構築手順に以下のコマンドが紹介されていたと思います

ビルドに必要なツールをインストールします。ターミナルを起動し、以下のコマンドを実行します。
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sonydevworld/spresense/master/installtools.sh
bash install-tools.sh


これを以下に変えて実行してみてください。
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sonydevworld/spresense/master/install-tools.sh
sed -i -E "s/libncurses5(-dev)?/libncurses-dev/g" install-tools.sh # 新しい行
bash install-tools.sh -r # -rを追加

その後は公式通り下記のようなコマンドが"kconfig-conf: command not found"を出力することなく動くはずです
sourse ~/spresenseenv/setup
tools/config.py examples/hello

